# How to cancel service on app termination Android

Tags: service, background

How can I stop a service from running in the background when my app is terminated? 
I want it the service to be active while the app is on background, but when the app is closed, I need the service to stop.

I call to start the service in the method onStop() that belong to myActivity
and i Stop it in the method onStart().

But the big problem is when i kill the app process I can see in the Logcat that the service is still running.

Can anyone tell me how should I run a service only when my app is on background?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to handle it manually, if you launch service with .bind() method in your Application class. As by documentation: "A bound service runs only as long as another application component is bound to it."

This info you can find in first 5 sentences in official manual http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html. Please consider to read the manual befor posting questions to SO.